# My tablet will no longer load and run the programs from usb cable using eclipse

Tags: android

I can no longer run any programs on my tablet from eclipse connected by usb cable. it keeps saying

> Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to
>   the front

this has happen before and I would turn off my tablet turn it back on and it would work fine. The complete log:

```
[2012-09-11 20:03:42 - TellaFortune] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-11 20:03:42 - TellaFortune] Performing besttecksolutions.tellafortune.TellaFortuneActivity activity launch
[2012-09-11 20:03:48 - TellaFortune] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-09-11 20:03:48 - TellaFortune] Starting activity besttecksolutions.tellafortune.TellaFortuneActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-09-11 20:03:49 - TellaFortune] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=besttecksolutions.tellafortune/.TellaFortuneActivity }
[2012-09-11 20:03:49 - TellaFortune] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Comment: The activity is still in background activity stack. Does it show the same message(s) when you do whatever change in the code?

Comment: The only time I have seen this happen is when there are no significant code changes so it does not build and deploy, and the app still has not been dumped from memory yet.  Can you see the activity in the DDMS tab,and if so can you stop the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have not edited the app itself or the service that runs in the background of your app. Eclipse will not reinstall an already installed app that is the same as an app already on the emulator or device. To solve this, edit any part of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit any file then save and run the app using Eclipse.  A duplicate answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9232430/1076574)